# User Interface Fuzzing - Android

Tags: android, user-interface, fuzzing

Is there any way to be able to fuzz test the UI portions of any application? Basically I just want to throw some random user input data (ie. press button, select tool, insert query into text box ...) to the app and see if it throws an error at some point.

Is this at all possible and can it be done on the Android SDK?

Comment: Have a look at [the monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alextsc suggested in a comment, the [UI/Application Exerciser Monkey](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html) does exactly what you want.  It also gives you many options on logging.